# How do I stop fetching the rest of the HTML document as soon as `axios` or `fetch` loads the `<head>` element?

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch

I am working with huge HTML files that are several megabytes of text each. Each document has only a set of specific elements in a `<head>` section that I actually need. Functions in my web app needs to send the GET request to partially load the HTML, with only that head section, without downloading the rest of the huge document.

Is there a way to use Axios interceptors, or some other method (`fetch` perhaps), only from the front-end, that could do this? Axios documentation is pretty sparse when it comes to interceptors.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/cancel#examples) is very similar on what you want do to.

You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) and get a stream reading data chunk by chunk. If you find `</header>` or `<body>` you can cancel reading from the stream stopping the request.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a good way to start with a solution. I will post here as soon as I finish with this optimization.